# jQuery pop-up menu on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here - http://desandr.ci-team.ru (mouse click on "КАТАЛОГ")

On FF and Chromium works fine - on "mouse in" under element shows menu.
On internet explorer 8 - nothing.

What's this, and how i can fix that?

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer are you trying this against?

Answer (score 0):

I got

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null

on line 5 of your popup.js file:

```
$(menu).css("left", $(this).offset().left);
```

This may be the reason why is not working. I tested on Chrome 18.0.1025.168

Check your toggle_menu function signature - right now doesn't take any param. And be careful tere's a difference between "this" and "$(this)"

In the ready function you can try

```
toggle_menu($(this));
```

and change the toggle_menu function to accept the element

```
function toggle_menu(myLink) {
    menu = myLink.attr("pp");
```